# why I am not able to install netbeans in my Mac?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I have downloaded java but still while installing netbeans it shows "No Java Found"[this is the installed version of java in my Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1n9Z.png),

[this is popping when I am trying to install netbeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNQ0W.png)

Comment: Netbeans 8.2 requires JDK 8 (and no later).  If you want to install using a later version of Java, you need Apache Netbeans; e.g. Apache Netbeans 12.2 runs on Java 15 as well as Java 8 & 11.

Comment: I want the netbeans 8.2 so I should only download JDK 8.2 ? so do I need to uninstall this one ?

Comment: Yes.  And install it.  But you need Java JDK 8 ... not JDK 8.2.  There is no such thing as JDK 8.2.  You shouldn't have to uninstall the Java 15 you currently have installed.  Different versions of Java can coexist.

Comment: even tho trying many times.... I can not completely uninstall java from Mac I mean the version I am having rn... how do I do it ?

Comment: there's no Java folder in my Mac still if I am running the command "java -version" its still showing the details

Comment: java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: Try searching for questions on how to uninstall Java from a Mac.